# how to pass Bitmap array between 2 activities

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap

I have been trying to pass bitmap array to another Activity for a week but I still can't do it

```
public class HomePage extends Activity {
private GridView gridView;
public Bitmap[] mBitArray;
public Bitmap[] mBitArray5;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.GridView1);
    mBitArray = new Bitmap[7];
    try
    {
        //these images are stored in the root of "assets"
        mBitArray[0] = getBitmapFromAsset("Gallary/g1p1.jpg");
        mBitArray[1] = getBitmapFromAsset("Gallary/g1p2.jpg");
        mBitArray[2] = getBitmapFromAsset("Gallary/g1p3.jpg");
        mBitArray[3] = getBitmapFromAsset("Gallary/g1p4.jpg");
        mBitArray[4] = getBitmapFromAsset("Gallary/g1p5.jpg");
        mBitArray[5] = getBitmapFromAsset("Gallary/g1p6.jpg");
        mBitArray[6] = getBitmapFromAsset("Gallary/g2p1.jpg");
       mBitArray[7] = getBitmapFromAsset("g2p2.jpg");
        mBitArray[8] = getBitmapFromAsset("hd-01.jpg");
        mBitArray[9] = getBitmapFromAsset("hd-02.jpg");
        mBitArray[10] = getBitmapFromAsset("hd-03.jpg");
        mBitArray[11] = getBitmapFromAsset("hd-04.jpg");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, mBitArray));
      gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int       position,
                long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),       FullImageActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);           
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}



public Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName) throws IOException {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream istr = assetManager.open(strName);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    istr.close();
    return bitmap;

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_home_page, menu);
    return true;
}

}






 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
 private Context mContext;
 private Bitmap[] mImageArray;


public ImageAdapter(Context context, Bitmap[] imgArray)
{
    mContext = context;
    mImageArray = imgArray;
}

public int getCount() {

    return mImageArray.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mImageArray[position];
}


public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {         
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(mImageArray[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(153, 150));
    return imageView;
}

public Bitmap getView1(int position) throws IOException {   

    AssetManager am = mContext.getAssets();
    String[] list = am.list("Gallary");
     BufferedInputStream buf = new               BufferedInputStream(am.open(list[position]));

     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);

 buf.close();
    return bitmap;
}
```

}

public class FullImageActivity extends Activity{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fullimage);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
     Intent i = getIntent();
     int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");


     ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this , null);


    //imageView.setImageBitmap(mBitArray[position]);
    trying to get mBitarray to fullscreenactivity to display a certain picture from the bitmap array
```

**so I want to pass MbitArray variable to Fullactivity class I tried to do it by Intent but I can't send Bitmap array maybe via constructor or inner class?**

Comment: Don't understand why you'd want to do this if you're just reading from your resources anyway. Just read it again instead of adding extra weight to your activity.

Comment: i did that exactly i defined the array again in the the fullimagieactivity but i get out of memory error after viewing 3~4 pics

Comment: did you recycle all your bitmaps?

Comment: no i didn't i searched about recycling and i have read somewhere "You should only recycle a bitmap when you do not need it anymore. However, you do need a bitmap when you want to display it. If you don't want to display it, then you can recycle a bitmap." so i should recycle my Bitmap array excluding the bitmap that being displayed? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) implements Parcelable, and you have an array of Bitmap, you should be able to pass them off:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
i.putExtra("bitmaps", mBitArray);
startActivity(i);
```

Then retrieve via [`getParcelableArrayExtra()`:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getParcelableArrayExtra%28java.lang.String%29)

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bitmap [] bitmaps = (Bitmap[]) i.getParcelableArrayExtra ("bitmaps");
```

You can also pass off the paths in a String array to `FullImageActivity`, then just remake them there, much like you did in your first Activity. To save code, if you choose this approach, making the method shared by making it static would be a good idea, just remember to pass off a Context instance so `getAssets()` can still be used:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(Context context, String strName) throws IOException {
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
    InputStream istr = assetManager.open(strName);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    istr.close();
    return bitmap;
}
```

Then to call, from `HomePage`

```
mBitArray[0] = getBitmapFromAsset(this,"Gallary/g1p1.jpg");
```

and from `FullImageActivity`

```
otherBitmapArray[0] = HomePage.getBitmapFromAsset(this, bitmapPaths[0]);
```

Comment: Just curious. Is performance affected If we pass a large bitmap?

Comment: @system32 Like anything being transferred, the biggger the size, the greater the performance hit. However, Parcelable is more efficient than Serializable, so this is still "better" in a sense. But how it holds up to re-reading from the paths, it depends on the device and bitmap sizes.

Comment: is there a difference between making the bitmap[] static and passing it in putExtra?

Comment: `Parcelable` is better than `Serializable` (They said). I don't think that `Serializable` can be also passed from Activity/Service to Activity/Service.

Comment: @JRowan Remember, a copy is made If you put model objects, bitmaps, or primitive types in `Bundle`.

Comment: @JRowan keeping it static means it belongs to the dalvik instance - Modification in `A` will be reflected in `B` if they both access the same static array. Making a Parcel doesn't keep references(this is still a way of "serializing"), and each array is local to the Activity.

Comment: @system32 Serializable can passed from Activity/Service to Activity/Service.

Comment: i tried to pass it via Intent but as long as i put the Bitmap array in my Homepage activity  `i.putExtra("bitmaps", mBitArray)` i get  !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!! error

Comment: @Joseph27 It is probably due to the [size of your bitmaps](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/cyKoStz-5Wc). If they're too big and you can't reduce their size at all, the other proper way is to remake them in your second Activity like I also outlined in my answer.

Comment: well i followed the other method and it's working but loading more than 6 pictures leads to Out Of Memory error i googled a bit about that error i found out that i need to recycle my Bitmaps when they are not used to free Some Memory so in my case after i select a certain picture from my gridview i don't need the Gridview anymore so shall i recycle it?  if you can tell me how to do it or provide me a tutorial/  link i will be pleased thanks :p

Comment: @Joseph27 just loop through the array in `onItemClick` and call `recycle()` on each bitmap it holds. You can also probably recycle them in `onPause()` Keep in mind though, that you are probably going to need to reload the bitmaps in `onResume()`.

Comment: i have tried to implement that so i recycled all Bitmap except first one and checked memory status it was 4x mb on First activity and became 2x mb on second activity but when i went back to firstactivity again the gridview was messy [ScreenShot](http://i45.tinypic.com/wiq5qe.png) and eventually crashes

Comment: @Joseph27 as I said *Keep in mind though, that you are probably going to need to reload the bitmaps in onResume().* this will include resetting the adapter.

Comment: i have read something about down scale "it’s not worth loading a 1024x768 pixel image into memory if it will eventually be displayed in a 128x96 pixel thumbnail in an ImageView." so when i used        `imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(153, 150));` did it down scaled the images to 153x150 pixels ?

Comment: @Joseph27 I don't regularly work with Bitmaps, so I can't have a big input on this. If you haven't done so already, follow [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap). It would probably be a good idea to also download their sample.